# Segmentation fault in below program

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve very basic problem [SPOJ CANDY](https://www.spoj.com/problems/CANDY/)
I am getting a segmentation fault when submitting the below solution.
But in Visual Studio its working fine.
I also declared variables by considering the size (sum as long long int)
because it can be large

1) Is it due to the fact that I am declaring the array inside the while loop;
should I declare that array outside of while loop so that for every test cases it uses that same array

2) Is every time loop runs(for every test cases) the new array is created, will it lead to garbage collection or compiler will automatically free the memory after every test cases (I know about dynamic memory allocation in that case we have to free memory explicitly ) can you tell me in which scope I
should declare the variables?

I got above doubts because segmentation fault is regarding memory access.

```
   #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;



    int main(){

        while(1){
            int n;
            int arr[10001];
            cin>>n;
            if(n==-1)
                break;
            long long int sum=0;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                int temp;
                cin>>temp;
                sum+=temp;
                arr[i]=temp;

            }
             int mean=sum/n;
            if((sum%n)!=0){
                cout<<-1<<endl;
                continue;
                }
             int count1=0;
             for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(arr[i]>mean){
                    count1+=(arr[i]-mean);

                }
             }
             cout<<count1<<endl;

        }

    }
```

Comment: You're not doing any dynamic memory allocation, that's using `new`. The array _should_ be fresh at each iteration of the `while`.

Comment: What value of n are you inputting? Please provide other input values as well for which you get a segmentation fault

Comment: what about the array in previous iteration will it lead to garbage collection or compiler will handle that?

Comment: Sorry@P.W but its working fine on my compiler its getting segmentation fault on submission to online judge spoj

Comment: Then what should i use other than cin? @MarcStröbel

Comment: Try with `cin.ignore()`.

Comment: did you try the provided example? `5
1
1
1
1
6
2
3
4
-1` input ends with -1, there a two data sets of input: 511116 and 234. Your program starts after the first set

Comment: Yes its working fine @MarcStröbel

Comment: Even i tried with my own test cases @MarcStröbel

Comment: can it be due to some space`" "` i might be missing because data is being taken from the file ?

Comment: http://spoj-sus.blogspot.com/2015/07/candy.html
This one is the solution of problem but i want to know where i am doing the mistake (segmentation fault)

Comment: from the sample: 'Output:
4
-1' you're printing the results after each block of input, not at the end. Try collecting the result and print it in a block at the end.

Comment: What if `n == 0`? That might cause some bad things to happen.

Comment: You are allocating 40KB on the stack, which the judging platform might not allow. Try moving the declaration of `arr` to the top level (so it resides in the .bss section) or using a heap allocation (`new int[10001]`) at the top of your main function.

Comment: @Botje you are  legend thanks a lot finally accepted

Comment: can you tell me why it happened is it due to too many arrays were created on stack when loop runs many times(for every test case),they last till main was on stack frame so we decided to remove our declaration from inside while loop to global declaration

Comment: I'll write a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably due to the stack allocation of `int arr[10001]`. This is most probably a 40kB allocation. Now, "allocation" is the wrong word, as it essentially just calculates the address of `arr` by doing something like `int * arr = STACK_POINTER-40004`.

Unfortunately, it is common to have the maximum stack size be 12 kB by default. This means that the operating system maps 12 kB into memory and sets `STACK_POINTER` to the top of that memory (assuming the stack grows downward).

So the net effect is that your `arr` pointer now points beyond the allocated stack -- into unallocated memory -- and the first access throws a segmentation fault. Normally you could fix this by upping the stack size with `ulimit -s`, but you do not have control over the judging platform used.

You have two options:

- use a heap allocation instead `int *arr = new int[10001]`. This is not affected by the initial stack size. In a normal program you should take care to clean this up, but for a short program like this it is not necessary.
- move the declaration of `int arr[10001]` to the top level. `arr` will point to a region known as the BSS section, which is initially zeroed. This is also not affected by the initial stack size.